# How to find the critical points of this function?

Tags: calculus

Find the critical points:

$f(x)=x^2\cdot\sin(1/x)$, where $x\ne 0$.

I used the first derivative and obtained:

$y'=2\cdot x\cdot\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)=0$

My main idea is to compute $x$ of the above equation and then use the second derivative test. But how to solve this equation? Thanks!

Comment: what is the value of $f'(n\pi)$, is it zero or undefined that you said the minimum is at this point and again for $\pi/2+n\pi$?

Comment: Sorry, I think the solution is wrong. Ok, omit it (but I don't know the right answer). Thank you!

Comment: Maple could not solve it, it might don't have any answer.

Comment: Supposing $\cos(1/x)\neq 0$ you could divide by the cosine to obtain $2x\tan (1/x) - 1 =0$. I don't know how to algebraically solve this either, but breaking it down to just one trigonometric function might simplify it a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the zeros of $\sin$ and $\cos$ never coincide ($\sin x = 0 \Rightarrow \cos x \neq 0$ and vice-versa) and since $f'$ is undefined at $x=0$, both, $\sin\frac1x$ and $\cos\frac1x$ must be nonzero in a critical point. This results in
$$x \tan\frac1x = \frac12$$
as equivalent formulation. [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2atan%281%2Fx%29+%3D+1%2F2) shows you a bunch of *numerical* solutions to this extremely singular problem, I doubt a general analytic formula can be found that easily.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is so difficult since this problem is from an elementary calculus textbook (pp.110 Ex.12) http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus/calculus.pdf

Comment: @Wanderer I am quite sure this is not solvable on an elementary level, or at least only specific zeros can be guessed and it can be said that there must be infinitely many. I imagine the true solutions _may_ be expressable in terms of the LambertW-function.